# Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown Mobile Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When my web design collapsed to mobile view, the dropdown menu doesn't push down the button below it, instead the menu shows up half way down the page. This only seems to happen on pages with the carousel function and lightbox2.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried this which was suggested in another topic:

```
.navbar-header {
position: relative;
```

z-index: 1;
}

Here's the Navbar code:

```
    <nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#defaultNavbar1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></button>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Photography<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="nature.html">Nature</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="people.html">People</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="construction.html">Contact Me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

and the scripts at the bottom`

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-3.3.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script>
    lightbox.option({
      'resizeDuration': 600,
      'wrapAround': true,
      'alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices': true,
      'fitImagesInViewport': true
    })
</script>`
```

Comment: could you provide a demo of the issue?  Is your menu typically under an image or something on desktop screens that is hidden on mobile? instead of position: relative, try position: absolute and top: 0. Just a guess

Comment: yeah the demo is here: www.tinajarrett.com and the position change didn't work, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it.

I switched css files earlier on in the day and I didn't realise a .dropdown-menu was missing from the bootstrap css.

```
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try putting the script tags at top ins. it might work.

Comment: That made the dropdown menu move upawards, but it's not inline with the rest of the buttons.